# Auto Scaling kafka partition on real time

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to know if we can auto scale the kafka partition in production system on real time? I can auto scale my consumer using kubernetes HPA however this will be concurrency with the number of partition that i have. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale up a topic yes but there is no automatic way to do so built into Kafka.

And even if it could be automated, you'll lose ordering of keyed-messages because now the producer will recompute the partition value where to send messages. Additionally, existing data in the partitions will not be automatically moved, so therefore scaling a topic to accommodate for existing load won't do any good because all new partitions will be empty

There is presently no way to scale down a topic, and even scaling down a cluster requires some manual intervention to drain the replicas and relocate partitions